# what is the best way to reliably remove unicode from strings

Tags: ruby

I have a variety of strings that I need to pull the 'TM', '(c)' etc from. These marks are in unicode. Right now I just want to pull all of the unicode out, once I get that working I'll be a little more selective and just pull out the legalese marks. Here's the code:

```
strings = ['Star Wars \u2122 2', 'Empire Strikes Back\u00C2\u00AE The Strikening',
       "Star Wars\u2122 2", "Empire Strikes Back\u00C2\\u00AE The Strikening"]

p strings.inspect

strings.each { |str|
  sub = str.gsub(/\\(u[(\d)a-fA-F]{4})/, "")
  p sub
}
```

Results in:

```
["Star Wars \\u2122 2", "Empire Strikes Back\\u00C2\\u00AE The Strikening", "Star Wars\u2122 2", "Empire Strikes Back\u00C2\\u00AE The Strikening"]
"Star Wars  2"
"Empire Strikes Back The Strikening"
"Star Wars\u2122 2"
"Empire Strikes Back\u00C2 The Strikening"
```

Works for single quotes, but not double. I understand that single quoted strings behave differently than double quoted strings. The issue here is that the strings that are being fed into this function are behaving as double quoted strings and breaking the code (substitution doesn't happen). I tried adding `sub('\\', '\\\\')` before the gsub but that didn't fix it.

I think I'm misunderstanding something about how strings behave in Ruby. How can I remove a unicode symbol from `"Star Wars\u2122 2"` reliably? The regex that I have isn't doing it.

Ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do `'String with ™ and ®'.delete '™®'`.

Also, what's your use case for removing non-ASCII characters? Unless you're doing something like building a URL slug, this is probably not a great idea to begin with. If you *are* building a URL slug, there are lots of gems (such as friendly_id) that will do this for you.

Comment: Neither. I just need to pull the names of the items and don't really care if they're trademarked etc. That did help though, thanks.

Comment: Ah, OK. I see. In that case, it's probably better not to think of it in terms of removing non-ASCII characters, and just remove the characters you don't want.

Answer (score 6):

This might be a little inefficient because it builds an array with every character in it, but it will work (in Ruby 1.9 and later):

```
s = "Empire Strikes Back\u00C2\u00AE The Strikening"
t = s.chars.select(&:ascii_only?).join    # => "Empire Strikes Back The Strikening"
```

When you write `'\u00C2'` you are not creating a string that contains unicode.  You are creating a string with 5 ASCII characters.  When you write `"\u00C2"` you are creating a string with a single non-ASCII unicode character.  That's one of the differences between double-quote notation and single-quote notation.

Comment: Hmm, I think I'd rather get the regex working. I suspect that I may need to deal with éê etc. I'm thinking in the long run I'll have to have multiple gsubs, one for each mark I need to pull.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation re: unicode in strings. That makes sense now. Seems perfectly designed for tripping up newbs, this '2 types of string' thing.